# ember.js - how to get parent route params in the adapter

Tags: javascript, ember.js, adapter

I'm currently working in a project powered by Ember-CLI with Ember 2.4.1 and Ember Data 2.4.0, and i cant figure out how to get all informations i need to set the buildURL for a model in the adapter file.

As i can't publish any code of the project, here is some example to illustrate the problem:

**router.js:**

```js
Router.map(function() {
  this.route('foo', {path: '/foo/:fooId'}, function(){
    this.route('bar', {path: '/bar/barId/list'});
  });
});
```

**adapter/bar.js:**

```
buildURL: function(model,id,snapshot,type){
  return '/api/foobar/:fooId/:barId/list
}
```

**The problem:**

So, based on the adapter below, the full URL should be something like: `http://localhost:3000/api/foo/2/bar/13/list` and the adapter needs the variables fooId = 2 and barId = 13 to build this URL... The problem is that there is no fooId and barId in the adapter.

So, what's the best approach to send this values to the adapter, and how to send other custom variables (if possible) ? e.g.: let's say i need to send a boolean 'foobarAttribute' to the adapter to generate the correct URL.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you looking for this? http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.BuildURLMixin.html

Comment: No... Actually, i need the params for foo and bar to be available in the adapter file.. Then i can build the URL with the buildURL method.

Comment: did you solve this?

Comment: @abFx, i solved this problem using a service. I just injected the service in the route and set all properties i need in the service (by the route) before send the request. So them, injecting this service in the adapter i could managed to get the properties i needed.

Comment: well not the answer that I was expecting, I managed to solve it but feels way too hackish, like your solution better, tnx! @RBR